# Why are comment ids in Wordpress continuous (unique)?

Tags: database, wordpress, comments

I notice that in WP blogs the comments order by continuous id (id=203, id=204 and so..).
while I understand the class names "parent" "child" - to sort the reply to thread, I didn't figure out why the id's are continuous - maybe to choose hide/show specific comments?

Comment: uh, what? What blog are you referring to? Link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to improve your question.

Comments have *UNIQUE* IDs because they are stored in their own table, and a One to Many relationship links the Posts with the Comments, thus, having a 'global' counter to them.

`Comment ID 1 => Post ID 1
Comment ID 2 => Post ID 1
Comment ID 3 => Post ID 2`

And so on, Post 1 has 2 comments, post 2 has one.

Comment: but the relation between comments to post can be set in the server side script, like you said. each comment has a relate id to the post.

what I meant to ask is why it has a unique ID in the html.
like in this WP blog:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/24/smashing-newsletter-challenge-and-giveaway/

thank you for your answer 
and sorry for being misunderstood.

Comment: @Sophia: I think it is just a design decision to make things simpler. For example, if the comments were marked 1,2,3 etc for each post, when you want to reply to a comment, the server side script must translate (post#, comment#) into the unique comment#. If it has the unique comment id as in the database, it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant "unique ID in the HTML":

1. Every ID in HTML [**has to be unique**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).
2. Even if there are no links to the separate comments on the page itself, like on [the page which you linked to](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/24/smashing-newsletter-challenge-and-giveaway/), IDs are still very handy when someone else wants to point to a particular comment from within another page. Like, when I want to point someone to the comment of Jeremy regarding email updates, I can [**simply do so**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/24/smashing-newsletter-challenge-and-giveaway/#comment-443232).